# How can I store information from a block in Swift?

Tags: swift, closures, block

Basically, I have an async networking function:

```
    func networking(callback:NSDictionary -> Void) {


     //stuff happens here



    let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
        if let error = error {
            print("ERROR: \(error)")
            return
        }
        do {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)
            //print(json)
            callback(json as! NSDictionary)

            if let dataDict = json["data"] as? [String:AnyObject],
                let rememberToken = dataDict["remember_token"] as? String {
                    self.rememberToken = rememberToken

                    //print("SUCCESS: \(rememberToken)")
                    // display success label &  make button to get schedules available
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    }

    task.resume()
}
```

And all I can do is print(json) data I'm getting back.  I really just want the remember token, and I'm storing it in a property.  The problem I'm having is if I call the property, I get nothing since the main thread executes first.  How can I access the remember token from the property AFTER it gets stored there?

Or can I store it somewhere else?

Whats the best way to do this?

Comment: You have to use the remember token only _inside_ the callback (i.e. near the line that you're printing the token).

Comment: Put the callback line **after** the expression to save the token

Comment: I moved the callback(json as! NSDictionary) to the line after self.rememberToken = rememberToken, but when I go to the next function, and try printing "self.rememberToken), i still get nothing

Comment: Is the token be saved at all?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can handle this:

1. Using Delegate and Protocols
2. Using Blocks

Preferable will be blocks.

There are tons of tutorial and SO answer on both of them so wont be providing the implementation here.